# looping through xml nodes where a type is "Array"

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Im having some trouble looping through some xml data.

The xml file is structured like this:

```
<users type="array">
 −<user>
   <id>14527576</id>
  </user>
 −<user>
   <id>14527576</id>
  </user>
 −<user>
   <id>14527576</id>
  </user>
```

My php to loop through it looks like this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($rawxml);
foreach($xml->users AS $key){
    $id = $key->user->{"id"};
```

But its not throwing errors, or returning anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users is your root element. You need just to enumerate it.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $rawxml );

foreach($xml as $user){
  print $user->id . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: its looping through the correct number of time, but its not selectiong the content of each node, its coming back blank

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. I just give you the right code that I tested and it works with your example :)
Each node in my code is visible in foreach loop in $user variable.

In your code you just have no variable in $xml->users, you can print_r your $xml variable and see it by yourself.